How to access data passed to jinija template from the webpage using javascript
I am passing a python list that contains two lists within it to a template. The code is as follows:
return render_template("result.html", result=pythonList)

where pythonList follows the structure:
[[a list of positive comments], [a list of negative comments]]

my result.html is as follows:
<div id = "commentsContainer">
</div>

<a onclick="displayPositive()">positive comments</a>
<a onclick="displayNegative()">negative comments</a>

<script>
   function displayPositive(){
      //code to assign the result[0] list to a const javascript variable called positive
      
   }
   function displayPositive(){
      //code to assign the result[1] list to a const javascript variable called negative
   }
</script>
                 

I tried to pass in the pythonList as json using
return render_template("result.html", result=json.dumps(pythonList))

but I am not sure if this is standard practice. I also dont know how to access this result json either. This is what I tried so far.

render_templates runs on the server side. Your variable will be only used while the template is being rendered, then the page will be sent to the client. You cannot access the data as a json with javascript this way. Here the documentation about template rendering
